# How to get the syntax hightlighting information for a selected keyword from DTE object (VS 2010)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte

Is it possible to get the information which syntax color scheme was used to highlight a selected symbol/keyword in the code editor?

I want to get the informations that is shown under **Tools->Options->Environment->Font and Colors** for the selected keyword.